# Does וְאִכָּבְדָ֤ה בְּפַרְעֹה֙ in 14:4 שמות also suggest weightier authority over Pharaoh?

Tags: hebrew, shemot-exodus, pharaoh

While in [Exodus (שמות) 14:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.14.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the primary meaning is "glory through Pharaoh," does וְאִכָּבְדָ֤ה בְּפַרְעֹה֙ give the sense of showing Ado-nai has weightier authority over Pharaoh, especially over his hardened heart (וְהַכְבֵּד֙‬ אֶת־לִבֹּ֔ו)?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.14.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.14.4.1&lang2=bi):

> ואכבדה בפרעה. **כְּשֶׁהַקָּבָּ"ה מִתְנַקֵּם בָּרְשָׁעִים שְׁמוֹ מִתְגַּדֵּל וּמִתְכַּבֵּד**, וְכֵן הוּא אוֹמֵר "וְנִשְׁפַּטְתִּי אִתּוֹ וְגוֹ'" וְאַחַר כָּךְ "וְהִתְגַדִּלְתִּי וְהִתְקַדִּשְׁתִּי וְנוֹדַעְתִּי וְגוֹ'" (יחזקאל ל"ח), וְאוֹמֵר "שָׁמָּה שִׁבַּר רִשְׁפֵי קָשֶׁת", וְאַחַר כָּךְ "נוֹדָע בִּיהוּדָה אֱלֹהִים" (תהלים ע"ו), וְאוֹמֵר "נוֹדַע ה' מִשְׁפָּט עָשָׂה" (שם ט'):
>
> ואכבדה בפרעה AND I WILL BE HONOURED THROUGH PHARAOH — **When the Holy One, blessed be He, takes vengeance on the wicked His name is magnified and honoured**. Thus, too, it states, (Ezekiel 38:22, 23) “And I will plead against him [with pestilence and with blood etc.]”, and afterwards, “Thus I shall be magnified and sanctified etc.” And it states, (Psalms 76:3) “There He broke the fiery shafts of the bow”, and afterwards (after He has done this) (v. 2) “In Judah is God known. “Further it states, (Psalms 9:17) “The Lord is known because He executeth judgment” (Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 14:4:2).